# NSOutlineView Never Reaching Datasource Children

Tags: swift, nsoutlineview

*Swift 4, Xcode 9.1*

I can only get the first level of items to render in my `NSOutlineView`. The child items never work. Below is my code with comments that show what gets logged to the console.

```
class SidebarSection{
  var title:String!
  var buttonHidden:Bool!
}

class SidebarItem{
  var title:String!
}

loadStuff(){
  print(sections) //[MyApp.SidebarSection, MyApp.SidebarSection]
  print(items) //[[MyApp.SidebarItem, MyApp.SidebarItem, MyApp.SidebarItem], [MyApp.SidebarItem]]

  sidebarOutlineView.reloadData()
}

//Over in my NSOutlineViewDelegate/Datasource...
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
  print(item) //nil
  print(sections) //[MyApp.SidebarSection, MyApp.SidebarSection]

  if let section = item as? SidebarSection{
    print("This never gets logged.")
    //...
  }else{
    //Sections
    print("Returned: \(sections.count)") //2
    return sections.count
  }
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
  print("\(index) / \(item)") //First time: 0 / nil; Second time: 1 / nil

  if let section = item as? SidebarSection{
    print("This never gets logged, either.")
    //...
  }else{
    //Items
    return sections[index]
  } 
}
```

I tried `if let section = item as? SidebarSection{}` right after my data gets added to the `sections` array, and it detects the type just fine. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually you have a root node and the `sections` are supposed to be the children of the root node and so on.

Comment: @vadian Hmm... do you know of an example where I can see that in action?